# AWS Lambda function being executed twice for every SQS trigger event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that is triggered whenever an SQS message is received on a FIFO queue. The structure of said function goes like this:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Takes each message present inside of the queue, and then operates with it.
    for record in event.get("Records"):
        # Here, all of the processing is done.
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "Function executed correctly."
    }
```

Now, whenever this function is triggered by an SQS message event, it executes normally, and ends without an error according to the logs. Nevertheless, it then is executed for a second time, seemingly out of nowhere, without an SQS message triggering it. Now, this second execution if not caused by the for loop, since removing it didn't solve the issue.

When looking at the logs, the `RequestID` for each one of the executions is different, but the `messageId` inside of the `Records` array of the event object is the same, for both executions. Also, for the first execution, the `ApproximateReceiveCount` inside of the `attributes` key is equal to 1, while in the second execution, it is set to 2.

So, for each event that triggers the lambda, even though there are no visible exceptions or mistakes in the logs, the function is being executed two times instead of one. Why could this be happening?

I've read a bit about idempotency and its importance for lambdas. One solution that I considered was use something like the `messageId` (which would be stored in a database) to check if sequential events are actually duplicates. So if the `messageId` of the previous execution event is the same as the one of the present event, then the present event is a duplicate and must not be processed.

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I focusing on a symptom and not in the disease? What do you all think?

Comment: Do you have partial processing enabled in your subscription? Normally, the lambda output is ignored for SQS subscriptions, but with partial processing, it's parsed. I don't know what happens if you return it in wrong format: probably the whole batch goes back to the queue. If you don't have partial processing, just don't return anything from the lambda, nobody reads it anyway.

Comment: How can I verify if I have it activated or not?

Comment: Lambda / configuration / triggers / SQS / Report batch item failures

Comment: It is not active I've removed the return from the lambda function Now what happens is that, even though there is no error present on the logs, the message is not being deleted after processing, and is instead sent to the DLQ.

Comment: Does the lambda's role have permissions to delete from the queue?

Comment: That was exactly it! I don't know how I missed something so obvious hahaha.

Answer (score 4):

> So, for each event that triggers the lambda, even though there are no visible exceptions or mistakes in the logs, the function is being executed two times instead of one. Why could this be happening?

##### Visibility

Your SQS queue might have shorter visibility timeout than the time it takes Lambda to process it.

If that happens, the message is returned to the queue before the lambda completes, with the receive count bumped up.

To work around that, you should either increase the queue visibility timeout, or implement a keepalive loop inside your lambda function, which calls [`ChangeMessageVisibility`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html) every so many seconds, extending its visibility just beyond the loop's duration. The latter is better if your message processing time varies greatly.

##### Permissions

To delete messages from the queue after successful processing, your Lambda role needs to have permissions to do that.

---

> I've read a bit about idempotency and its importance for lambdas. One solution that I considered was use something like the messageId (which would be stored in a database) to check if sequential events are actually duplicates. So if the messageId of the previous execution event is the same as the one of the present event, then the present event is a duplicate and must not be processed.

If processing a message twice is a problem big enough for your use case that it warrants building a database, probably SQS is not the right technology for that. It's designed for use cases which are naturally idempotent, like checking a completion checkbox in a distributed asynchonous process or something like that. It's not a big deal if you mark something as completed twice, because it just stays completed.

You might consider Kinesis or Managed Kafka or similar event stream solutions that don't mix state and data the way SQS does. In proper event streams, the data is persistent and immutable, and the only tiny piece of state that is stored in your Lambda/Kinesis subscription is its position(s) in the shard(s).

This way, the chance of double processing happening is much smaller.